# append html <a> tag in php

Tags: php, html, email

i am using `php mail` function

```
$message.='Hi '.$name.', You have been invited to join this, you can do so by following <a href="https://www.google.com.pk/">This link</a>, '.$text.'';
        $headers = "From: abc@gmail.com" . "\r\n" ."CC: abc@hotmail.com";

        $emailTo = $email;
        $subject = "Invitation email";
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

it is working fine, but this `<a>` i am using is either not appended right or not written syntatically correct, the email i get is.

Hi this, You have been invited to join Maggie, you can do so by following

```
 <a
href="http://google.com.pk" class="link"
id="position">this link</a>
```

, this is a sample email to send.

the tag is written as is, how can i append this `<a>` into this mail?

Comment: You need to set `html header` for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify headers. Take a look.

```
$message = "Hello, hope you are doing fine.<br>"
    . "Please check this:<br>"
    . "<a href=\"$url-here\">Anchor text</a>";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"
    . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"
    . 'From: youremail@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n";
```

Do use " (double quotes) for message.

Answer (score 1):

Change your headers to or add these

```
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Set headers might help :

```
$headers = "Reply-To: FROM_NAME <FROM_EMAIL>\r\n";
$headers.= "From: FROM_NAME <FROM_EMAIL>\r\n";
$headers.='X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers.= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this on top:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html");
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers shoulds contain the content type...
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";